# Is there an advantage to using --no-metadata in git svn clone?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-svn

I'm doing a one-way convert from an SVN repository to a Git repository using `git svn clone`.  Most examples do this with the `--no-metadata` flag - is there an advantage to using this flag?

I understand that the flag removes the SVN revision numbers.  I can think of reasons why it may be useful to keep these around (such as referring back to specific commits mentioned in bug tracking software).

What are the arguments **for** using the `--no-metadata` flag?  Is there any benefit other than a sensation of breaking all ties?

Comment: The metadata is for getting information from git back to subversion.  If you don't need to ever do that, you don't need the metadata.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

One argument for using `--no-metadata` is that it doesn't change your commit messages. So even if you fetch from different locations, the commit messages will be the same and thus the commit hashes will be the same.

As an example, if I `git svn init` a repo from a local `file:` URL and later pull from an `https:` URL, every commit in the repo will be duplicated, since all of the commits with `git-svn-id: file:///`... will be fetched as `git-svn-id: https:///`... and encoded with new SHA1's.

If I specify `--no-metadata` then the commit message and this sha1 has will be the same and I can fetch from either the local filesystem or the subversion server because there will only be a single copy of any given svn commit in the git repo.

Personally I would prefer it if there were a *minimal metadata* option, which recorded the subversion revision id, but not the full metadata, but without messing around with `git-filter-branch` we are stuck with all or nothing.

Comment: Another problem this metadata can cause is when git thinks it should be creating the commit from different roots, e.g. `/project/trunk` vs. just `/project`. This can cause the commits to be distinct in git even though they're the same in SVN.

Answer (score 10):

It is actually not recommended:

> This option is NOT recommended as it makes it difficult to track down
>   old references to SVN revision numbers in existing documentation, bug
>   reports and archives. If you plan to eventually migrate from SVN to
>   git and are certain about dropping SVN history, consider
>   git-filter-branch(1) instead. filter-branch also allows reformatting
>   of metadata for ease-of-reading and rewriting authorship info for
>   non-"svn.authorsFile" users.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. We know it's not recommended, but it is there; what is the point in it, what good can it do? What reasons might one have for wanting to use this option?