# Git log doesn't display latest commits fetched from remote svn repo

Tags: git, svn, version-control, version-control-migration

I've migrated the trunk directory of a project in svn to git using "git svn clone...". After a few commits have been made in svn, I execute "git svn fetch". This fetches the new commits in svn and checksums are generated for each commit. Now if I "git log", the commits I just fetched aren't displayed. However, if I "git show *checksum*" the commit is shown.
The changes are probably in some remote tracking branch. How do I merge them to master?

Comment: Does `git log trunk` help?

Answer (score 0):

I recently cloned an svn over to git using git-svn, and you have to make sure that you are referencing the correct branches. SVN uses the branch 'trunk' as its "base" if you will, and when you do a git svn fetch, it takes all of the revisions onto trunk and converts them into a trunk branch in your git repo.

On the other hand, git tends to use 'master' as it's "main branch" so you are going to have to rebase master off of trunk, or merge trunk into master.

Comment: Also, checkout the trunk branch `git checkout trunk` and then try running `git log` and all of those commits should be there. IF not, then the conversion was not done correctly

Comment: I've only migrated the a particular project from the trunk folder (we have a shared trunk in svn) so there wouldn't be any such branch in git. The one-time migration that I made was perfect but now I'm trying to fetch new commits that were made in svn but aren't present in git. Even "git svn rebase" doesn't work--throws this error: Unable to determine upstream SVN information from working tree history. It might be because I used the --no-metadata option.

Comment: Okay, I'd say you're probably right based on reading the answers to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8333870/is-there-an-advantage-to-using-no-metadata-in-git-svn-clone. It seems that if you want to go back and fetch the --no-metadata flag might cause some issues